# React & Redux, Update state, Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The problem I'm having is in my save data round trip.

The error: browser.js:34 Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `profile.user.alias`.

I'm new to React & Redux but I think I've done everything by the book. What am I missing?

1. I create a local state in the component and assign the object returned from mapStateToProps.
2. I setState on onChange of text fields.
3. On save click, I call the action defined in mapDispatchToProps passing it the local state. Note, the mapped action is a Thunk function since I use REST Api to save date on server.
4. Server saves the data and returns the same object with new Ids etc. filled in.
5. In fetch.then() I dispatch an action passing the object returned from the server.

The error is on the dispatch line.

```
export function setUserProfile (profile) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return setProfile(profile)  <-- the API call
            .then(p => {
                dispatch(handleSetProfileSuccess(p));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw error;
            });
    };
```

I've been wrestling with this error since yesterday. I've tried all tricks I've found including changing to createReducer from Redux-Starter-Kit.

I've made sure that the exact same chain of objects, actions, reducers, etc. that I use in the 'set' are the same as in the 'get' action that works.

```
export function handleSetProfileSuccess (profile) {
    return { type: types.SET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS, profile };
}


export function setUserProfile (profile) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return setProfile(profile)   <--- the api call with fetch
            .then(p => {
                dispatch(handleSetProfileSuccess(p));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw error;
            });
    };

// the action is never dispatched on save since the error is on the dispatch line above.
// the Redux way
export default function profileReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, ...action.profile };
        case types.SET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, ...action.profile };
        default:
            return state;
    }
} 


// the redux-starter-kit way
const profileReducer=createReducer({}, {
    GET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS: (state, action) => state=action.profile,
    SET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS: (state,action) => state=action.profile
});
```

The whole round trip works. The new data is saved on the server and the returned object from the server is correct. The argument 'p' in the .then() call does contain the correct data. But it crashes on the call to

```
dispatch(handleSetProfileSuccess(p));
```

EDIT: Here's the code snippets from profile.js

```
// profile.js
state = { ...this.props.profile };

// on save click handler
setData = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // validate stuff here
    this.props.setProfile(this.state).then(() => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            ...this.props.profile
        }));
    });
};

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.user, 
        profile: state.profile 
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getProfile: profileActions.getUserProfile,
    setProfile: profileActions.setUserProfile
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Profile);
```

Please help. I'm all out of options.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but this doesn't need a return: `return setProfile`.

Comment: does the reducer get called for type SET_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS?

Comment: No. The reducer is never reached since the error is on the dispatch call.

Comment: Can you show any other places where you might be accessing that state path?  Are you reading it in a `mapState` function, or in a component file?  (Also, I'll point out that this is exactly why RSK adds a "mutation detection" middleware by default - to catch these kinds of errors.)

Comment: The setProfile function is defined in a module for all APIs. It returns a promise.

Comment: @markerikson, I added some more code snippets.

Comment: Hmm.  Not seeing anything immediately obvious in that code.  Is there _anywhere_ else in your code that you are accessing `state.profile.user.alias`?

Answer (score 0):

it is likely that you are mutating a prop passed by react-redux.

Check all code where you are using `props.profile` or `props.user`, code like the following could be the culprit

```
props.profile.friends.splice(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The state mutation error happens when you mutate the props received and dispatches an action with that mutated props. So to do such dispatches, copy the props to a local state while receiving it, make the changes to the state and dispatch the action with the state.

If the props received is a nested object do deep copying, using
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify());`

So in your code, before making a dispatch copy the props to a state and make the dispatch with the state.